# ASP.NET MVC4 + Razor on Mono + EF 6 DateTime crash

Tags: c#, asp.net-mvc-4, iis, mono

I am trying to run an application with Mono. It runs fine on IIS, but I want it run on Mono. But it always throw this to me:

> The 'CreateDate' property on 'Article' could not be set to a 'System.String' value. You must set this property to a non-null value of type 'System.DateTime'.

The fact is that the place where it is thrown is this:

```
public Article[] Select(int number)
        {
            return DbContextProvider.Current.Set<Article>()
                .OrderByDescending(n => n.CreateDate)
                .Take(number)
                .ToArray();
        }
```

There is nowhere any usage of System.String. Actually, the only place it gets converted to a string, is here:

```
@using BaseSite.Extensions.DateTimeExtensions
@model Classic.Views.Home.Articles.ArticleViewModel

<div class="article-wrapper">
    <div class="article-title">
        @Html.ActionLink(Model.Title, "Index", "Articles", new RouteValueDictionary{{"articleId", Model.ArticleId}}, null)
    </div>
    @Html.Raw(Model.Text)
    <div class="article-data date">
        @Html.ActionLink(Model.UserId, "Index", "Profile", new RouteValueDictionary{{"userId", Model.UserId}}, null),
        @Model.CreateDate.Format(true)
    </div>
</div>
```

But the error is being thrown a way before that. And, it works on IIS, only on Mono there is such a strange bug.

Database table layout is:

```
CREATE TABLE [dbo].[Articles](
    [ArticleId] [uniqueidentifier] NOT NULL,
    [UserId] [nvarchar](30) COLLATE SQL_Latin1_General_CP1_CI_AS NOT NULL,
    [CreateDate] [datetime2](7) NOT NULL,
    [Title] [nvarchar](50) COLLATE SQL_Latin1_General_CP1_CI_AS NOT NULL,
    [Text] [nvarchar](max) COLLATE SQL_Latin1_General_CP1_CI_AS NOT NULL,
PRIMARY KEY CLUSTERED 
(
    [ArticleId] ASC
)WITH (PAD_INDEX = OFF, STATISTICS_NORECOMPUTE = OFF, IGNORE_DUP_KEY = OFF, ALLOW_ROW_LOCKS = ON, ALLOW_PAGE_LOCKS = ON) ON [PRIMARY]
) ON [PRIMARY] TEXTIMAGE_ON [PRIMARY]
```

The mapping classes:

```
using System;

namespace BusinessObjects.Articles
{
    public class Article
    {
        public Guid ArticleId { get; set; }
        public string UserId { get; set; }
        public DateTime CreateDate { get; set; }

        public string Title { get; set; }
        public string Text { get; set; }
    }
}

using System.Data.Entity;

namespace BusinessObjects.Articles
{
    public class ArticleMapper : IDbMapper
    {
        public void Map(DbModelBuilder modelBuilder)
        {
            var entity = modelBuilder.Entity<Article>();

            entity.HasKey(n => n.ArticleId);
            entity.Property(n => n.ArticleId).IsRequired();

            entity.Property(n => n.UserId).IsRequired().HasMaxLength(30);
            entity.Property(n => n.Title).IsRequired().HasMaxLength(50);
            entity.Property(n => n.Text).IsRequired().IsMaxLength();
        }
    }
}
```

And yeah. I have also other tables with DateTime, they all get that error. And they all runs normally on IIS (MS Stack), it only bugs on Mono + xsp4.
Can anyone provide any help? I am lost with that weiredness.

PS: I tried nearly all mono versions, right now I am at Mono git master 3.8.1 (master/38c3874), same thing with 3.6, 3.2.8 etc

Comment: I think I had problems with datetime2 as a SQL column on Mono before, seems it's not supported yet. Can you try removing the column and see if it works then?

Comment: Aha, so it's datetime2 column on Mono bug? Because I consider migrating to PgSql, can that help?

Comment: Did it work without the datetime2? Migrating to PgSql could help in this case, as I don't think it uses that type.

Comment: I migrated to PgSql, so problem gone

Answer (score 1, accepted):

As Alexander Köplinger mentioned, seems to be a bug of "datetime2" inside Mono. Fixed by migrating away from MsSql to PostgreSql - it was in the plans.