# Mono InvalidOperationException on DateTime column (SQL Server)

Tags: c#, entity-framework, datetime, mono, linq-to-entities

I can't map DateTime2 columns in SQL Server to DateTime column on Mono on OS X.

created_at is defined as DateTime2 non-nullable column in sql side, and I defined as `public DateTime created_at { get; set; }` in c# side.

I get this exception:

`InvalidOperationException: The 'created_at' property on 'revision' could not be set to a 'System.String' value. You must set this property to a non-null value of type 'System.DateTime'.`

However, the same definition works on when running my project on Windows.

Comment: I am having the same problem. Unfortunately it seems that it is a current Mono limitation, as I stumbled upon [this question](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/25577219/asp-net-mvc4-razor-on-mono-ef-6-datetime-crash).
How did you work around it?

Comment: @unagi SQL server reports this column as string in the legacy protocol version which mono implements. When I bump the protocol version, server closes connection after I sent login packet. I ended up patching GetValue function somewhere: I tried to parse *every string* to datetime when it throws exception i return the string otherwise I return datetime. But it will throw exception if you store datetime as a string, hence I didn't open a merge request to Mono repository (bad workaround). Looking for the code will keep you posted.

Comment: @unagi see the last post at https://github.com/mono/mono/pull/1773#issuecomment-136125909 This was the thing i implemented and works great for my own case

Answer (score 0):

Please Try This

```
public DateTime created_at { get; set; }
```

it will helps you...